# Bug: Safe handle has been closed (NServiceBus / NancyFX)

Tags: nservicebus, windows-authentication, nancy

I've been debugging for days trying to find the root cause and it seems that it is caused by simply sending two messages.

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule(IBus bus)
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => 
        {
            bus.Send<Command1>(m => { m.Id = "WHATEVER"; });
            return "OK";
        };
    }
}

public class Command1 : ICommand
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Command2 : ICommand
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Handler1 : IHandleMessages<Command1>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Handle(Command1 message)
    {
        Bus.Send<Command2>(m => { m.Id = message.Id; });
    }
}

public class Handler2 : IHandleMessages<Command2>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Handle(Command2 message)
    {

    }
}

public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

        LogManager.Use<DefaultFactory>().Directory(container.Resolve<IRootPathProvider>().GetRootPath());

        var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
        configuration.EndpointName("MyEndpoint");
        configuration.DisableFeature<NServiceBus.Features.SecondLevelRetries>(); // TODO
        if (Debugger.IsAttached) configuration.EnableInstallers();
        configuration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();

        var bus = Bus.Create(configuration).Start();

        container.Register<IBus>(bus);
    }
}
```

Gives me error:

> Key   Value CorrId    a539e440-0b7a-4283-a20a-a472006da636\0
>   NServiceBus.ContentType   text/xml
>   NServiceBus.ConversationId    2b38fa53-749b-43e4-aa0f-a472006da63a
>   NServiceBus.CorrelationId a539e440-0b7a-4283-a20a-a472006da636
>   NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes  Command1, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.ExceptionType   System.ObjectDisposedException
>   NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.HelpLink
>   NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.Message Safe handle has been closed
>   NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.Source  mscorlib
>   NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.StackTrace  System.ObjectDisposedException:
>   Safe handle has been closed    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean&
>   success)    at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle,
>   Boolean& success)    at
>   Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle
>   TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle
>   TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)
>   at
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle
>   tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass)    at
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()    at
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()    at
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()    at
>   NServiceBus.Impersonation.Windows.WindowsIdentityEnricher.MutateOutgoing(LogicalMessage
>   logicalMessage, TransportMessage transportMessage) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Impersonation\Windows\WindowsIdentityEnricher.cs:line
>   16    at
>   NServiceBus.MutateOutgoingPhysicalMessageBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\MutateOutgoingPhysicalMessageBehavior.cs:line
>   12    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at NServiceBus.SerializeMessagesBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\SerializeMessagesBehavior.cs:line
>   38    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.CreatePhysicalMessageBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\CreatePhysicalMessageBehavior.cs:line
>   58    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.PopulateAutoCorrelationHeadersForRepliesBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Sagas\PopulateAutoCorrelationHeadersForRepliesBehavior.cs:line
>   46    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.MutateOutgoingMessageBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\MutateOutgoingMessageBehavior.cs:line
>   28    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at NServiceBus.SendValidatorBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\SendValidatorBehavior.cs:line
>   20    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   52    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.Execute[T](BehaviorChain`1
>   pipelineAction, T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   129    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.InvokePipeline[TContext](IEnumerable`1
>   behaviors, TContext context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   85    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.InvokeSendPipeline(DeliveryOptions
>   deliveryOptions, LogicalMessage message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   114    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.InvokeSendPipeline(DeliveryOptions
>   sendOptions, LogicalMessage message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   624    at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(SendOptions
>   sendOptions, LogicalMessage message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   610    at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Send[T](Action`1
>   messageConstructor) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   455    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry.Invoke(Object handler,
>   Object message, Dictionary`2 dictionary) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\MessageHandlerRegistry.cs:line
>   126    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry.InvokeHandle(Object
>   handler, Object message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\MessageHandlerRegistry.cs:line
>   84    at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.b__1(Object
>   handlerInstance, Object message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line
>   40    at NServiceBus.InvokeHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\InvokeHandlersBehavior.cs:line
>   24    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.cs:line
>   17    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line
>   45    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line
>   23    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line
>   24    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at NServiceBus.CallbackInvocationBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\CallbackInvocationBehavior.cs:line
>   22    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line
>   47    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line
>   20    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Subscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptions\SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.cs:line
>   31    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line
>   42    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at NServiceBus.ChildContainerBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ChildContainerBehavior.cs:line
>   17    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at
>   NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Monitoring\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line
>   23    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   94    at NServiceBus.AuditBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context,
>   Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Audit\AuditBehavior.cs:line
>   20    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   52    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.Execute[T](BehaviorChain`1
>   pipelineAction, T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   129    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.InvokePipeline[TContext](IEnumerable`1
>   behaviors, TContext context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   85    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.InvokeReceivePhysicalMessagePipeline()
>   in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   102    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender,
>   TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   826    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage
>   msg) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line
>   411    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage
>   message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line
>   344    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessage
>   message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line
>   228    at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Action() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line
>   266

The problem only occurs when I enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous.

Comment: Duplicate question https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/lA7qYOMrqbU/XXs3SfAGcYAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this looks like a bug specifically in NancyFX.

The problem is that the proposed WindowsIdentityEnricher only checks for null. Since `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` exists the first check passes, but the `Name` has a Disposed error.

I put a watch on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Name`. It fails somewhere in between `MsmqMessageSender.Send()` and `MsmqDequeueStrategy.OnPeekCompleted()`, which suggests to me that it is a bug outside of NService.

As a work around I added a new mutator to re-populate the principle.

```
public class PrincipalEnricher : IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages
{
    public void MutateOutgoing(LogicalMessage logicalMessage, TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    }
}
```

I am not familiar enough with NService to know if it is deterministically called before the `WindowsIdentityEnricher` mutator or just a coincidence.

Hope this helps someone.

PS. By coincidence I notice the same error in MVC if I start the bus and send a message in the same controller, and not in the Global class.

Answer (score 2):

NServiceBus version 5.1+ fixes this issue.
This issue has been reported before in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/lA7qYOMrqbU/XXs3SfAGcYAJ

Comment: btw I'm using version 5.2 and still have this error

Comment: @theother bummer :(  Can you please post a bit more detail in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/lA7qYOMrqbU/XXs3SfAGcYAJ so we can get to the bottom of it, thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with this group, plus I don't think it is the same bug. I would appreciate it if you could follow through on this one. Thanks!